# problems with native libs in android 7

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zbar, zbar-sdk

For barcode scanning we are using zbar library it is working fine belwo Android 7 versions but in my samsung tab A(Android version 7.0) I am fasing issue with native libs like libiconv.so:text relocations and libzbarjni.so: text relocations. [image]

Comment: Please consult log for details.

Comment: your app contains library with text relocations ... recompile 'em with newer NDK ... also question was already asked here - use search option